# Growing bar animation in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to create a "growing bar" animation in **css**?

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWIkw.gif

if no is this javascript the right approach?

```js
window.addEventListener("Click",test());
i=0;
function test(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      i+=5;
      document.getElementById('growing-bar').style.height = i + 'px';
      if(i<99){
          test();
      }
  },50);
}
```

```css
#growing-bar{
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="growing-bar"></div>
```

working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xu1bf9o6/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you also want that stepwise-style animation or a smooth growing one?

Comment: by the way, the answer is yes. It's doable in CSS.

Comment: @timolawl a smooth one, sorry for the confusion. thanks, do you know which animation type I should take? translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS solution:

```css
div {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: black;
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { height: 100px; };
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `transform-origin` set to `top`, `translate` set to `0%, 0%`, `transform` `rotate` set to `180deg` for `height` animation to be applied vertically; include `forwards` at `animation` declaration

```css
#growing-bar{
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  margin:50px;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(180deg);
  animation: grow 20s forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    height:0px;
  }
  to {
    height:150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="growing-bar"></div>
```

Comment: wow, interesting approach, but is it just my slow machine or doesn't the bar grow linearly? seems like it slows down at the end...is this just me?

Comment: @TroxlerP Try adding `linear` before `forwards` at `css` at stacksnippets, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function